# XY scaling on graphael horizontal barcharts

Tags: javascript, graphael

I want my x axis to have a max (say 100)and scale the actual x values accordingly, so that the chart always has the same proportions, rather than the proportions being relative to the min and max value supplied in graphael horizontal barchart